# Python: the major differencies in the use of proxies and user-agent strings

Tags: python, proxy, web-scraping, urllib2, urllib

I have some incomprehension in webscraping.
I have problems with parse data from some urls (some urls I should open more than once), but there is a captcha and it block my ip.
I try to find the way to get around this.
I saw many ways:
1) using proxy
2) substitution of user-agent string
Firstly, I tried to use proxies. I try to use it in `urllib.urlopen` and

```
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({some proxy})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

It's not solve my problem. I've always got an error, almost always `IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 10061] ����������� �� �����������,`, and I can't understand, why I have it.
And I started to try another way.
I used another user-agent string and sometimes I've got `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10054, ''))`.
But for some urls it works while proxies don't.
I try to understand why does it happen because user-agent doesn't change my ip, but proxy should change my ip, but it's not work.
Can anybody explain me this and do it information clear to me.

Comment: all computers in local network use the same external IP - so you can have many users with the same IP but with different `user-agent` (so blocking only by IP is not fair).

Comment: did you check proxy in different program - ie. in web browser ? maybe this proxy doesn't work and you can't connect to proxy. `10061` may mean that server is turn off or too busy to answer. Normally web server sends captcha or HTML with warning but it does not refuse socket connection. It can be different problem.